# While loop: problems resetting counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I am trying to reset a loop so that it starts again. To do this I have added an `if` statement saying that if the counter (i) reaches a predetermined amount reset it back to 0:

```
var i = 0;

while (i < 3) {

    //DO STUFF

    i++; 
    if(i == 3){
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

However, this just crashes my page.

The code looks fine to me. I don't know what I've done wrong.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why do you want to repeat the loop ? And how many times?

Comment: @TeeDeJee I want to make a carousel/image slide type script. So I would like it to repeat infinetly

Comment: How did you get 2,304 reputation points if you don't see that this creates an infinite loop? oO

Comment: @KeVin 'cause I havent used JS in ages, its 12:30am here and I cant delete the question :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating and endless loop. If you get to `i=3` you start the loop again and again.
So your page just crashes.

If you want a carousel just use a lightweight ready made script such as http://baijs.nl/tinycarousel/

Comment: Yeah thats what kind of I want to do. Its for a carousel type script. Any way around this? Better to put it in a function and trigger the function over and over?

Comment: You want to create a carousel that scrolls automatically ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs into an [Infinite Loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_loop).
`i` is being incremented up to 3 and because of you `if` statement it is then being reset to 0. For your browser this means your code runs forever and exceeds the maximum script execution time.
What are you trying to achieve?